# Generate a random number, but every random seconds in LUA/Love2d

Tags: random, lua, love2d

I am trying to generate a random number, every random seconds (the final purpose would be to change the color of a block from time to time, randomly).

For that, I am using the Hump library (http://vrld.github.io/hump/#hump.timer).

Here is my code at the moment, I am true beginner in LUA/Love2d coding.
It generates a number, and displays it every seconds, instead of every random seconds... (but the random seconds is also generated).
I don't really understand why it is not working.

```
local Timer = require "timer"

function love.load()
    text="t"
    number2=1
end

local f = function()
math.randomseed(os.time())
    number = math.random( 2,10 )
    text="in " .. number2 .. " seconds (random)...  random number =" .. number
    return true
end

function love.update(dt)

    number2 = math.random( 2,4 ) 
    Timer.update(number2)
    Timer.addPeriodic(number2, f)
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.print( text, 330, 300 )
end
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Call `math.randomseed(os.time())` just once in your program.

Comment: my bad, I removed the one in the love.update but the issue remains.

Comment: In the updated code, you are still calling `f` in `love.update`, which means `math.randomseed` is still called more than once.

Comment: ok I understand better now. I needed to also move the 'number2' in a function and not call 'f' in 'love.update'... but I had an issue where the text was printed every 0.1seconds, so I changed the code again and came up with something alsmot similar to what Henri Ilgen suggested below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am not familiar with Hump, it seems that you can easily use the timer's add function for your purpose, as it will call the function exactly once after x seconds, allowing you to schedule the next execution with a different delay:

```
local timer = require("timer")
local text = ""

local function tick()
  -- Generate random number
  local newNumber = math.random(2, 10)
  local newDelay  = math.random(2,  4)
  text = ("Current number: %d, next in %d seconds!"):format(newNumber, newDelay)

  -- Actually schedule the next call
  timer.add(newDelay, tick)
end


function love.load()
  tick()
end

function love.update(dt)
  timer.update(dt)
end

function love.draw()
  love.graphics.print(text, 330, 300)
end
```